# Showing that an integral is the same as the principal Log branch

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I had asked a previous question trying to determine whether this integral was defined for a cut $z\in \mathbb{C} - \{x + 0i $ for all $x\leq0 \}$

$$f(z)=\int_{1}^{z} \frac{dl}{l}.$$

I am now wondering how I would show that this function is indeed the principal branch of Log. I'm guessing I would just find the antiderivative, which is $\log(z) - \log(1) = \log(z)$. Would that be it? And it's the principal branch because the cut $z\in \mathbb{C} - \{x + 0i\}$ is the definition of the principal branch?

Or would I have to verify that the curve is closed and other considerations prior to leaping to this step?

Comment: Is your domain $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$?

Comment: Non-positive x-axis, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {f(z+h)-f(z)} h =\frac 1  h\int_{[z,z+h]} \frac 1 l dl \to \frac 1 z $ as $h \to 0$. Thus, $f(z) $ and $Log \,z$ (the Principal logarithm) both have the same derivative and they both vanish at $1$. The domain is an open connected set.  Hence, the two functions  are identical.